# Intuition behind the Z algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The Z algorithm is a string matching algorithm with O(n) complexity.

One use case is finding the longest occurence of string A from string B. For example, the longest occurence of `"overdose"` from `"stackoverflow"` would be `"over"`. You could discover this by calling the Z algorithm with a combined string `"overdose#stackoverflow"` (where # is some character not present in either string). The Z algorithm would then try to match the combined string with itself - and create an array z[] where z[i] gives you the length of longest match starting from index i. In our example:

```
index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
string o  v  e  r  d  o  s  e  #  s  t  a  c  k  o  v  e  r  f  l  o  w
z    (21) 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

There are plenty of code implementations and mathematically oriented explanations of the algorithm, here are some good ones:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/z-algorithm-linear-time-pattern-searching-algorithm/
http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107

I can see *how* it works, but I don't understand *why*. It seems almost like black magic. I have a very strong intuition that this task is supposed to take `O(n^2)`, yet here is an algorithm that does it in `O(n)`

Comment: This is one of those elegant algorithms that hides a lot of complexity. Those references you gave are not good. Several others I looked at - including slide sets for college courses - were also pretty poor. Try this one and work through the explanation with some examples. https://ivanyu.me/blog/2013/10/15/z-algorithm/

Answer (score 2):

I don't find it completely intuitive either, so I think that I qualify for answering. Otherwise I'd just say that you don't understand because you're an idiot, and surely that's not the answer your hoping for :-)

Case in point (citation from an explanation):

```
Correctness is inherent in the algorithm and is pretty intuitively clear.
```

So, let's try to be even more intuitive...

First, I'd guess that the common intuition for O(n^2) is this: for a string of length N, if you're dropped at a random place i in the string with no other information, you have to match x (< N) characters to compute Z[i]. If you're dropped N times, you have to do up to N(N-1) tests, so that's O(n^2).

The Z algorithm, however, makes good use of the informations you've gained from the past computations.

Let's see.

First, as long as you don't have a match (Z[i]=0), you progress along the string with one comparison per character, so that's O(N).
Second, when you find a range where there's a match (at index i), the trick is to use clever deductions using the previous Z[0...i-1] to compute all the Z values in that range **in constant time**, without other comparisons **inside that range**. The next matches will only be done on the right of the range.

That's how I understand it anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a deeper understanding for this algorithm hence I found this question.

I didn't understand the [codeforces post](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107) initially, but later I found it is good enough for understanding, and I noticed that the post was not entirely accurate, and it omitted some steps in the thinking process, making it a bit confusing.

Let me try to correct the inaccuracy in that post, and clarify some of the steps I think may help people connect the dots to a line. In this process, I hope we can learn some intuition from the original author. In the explanation, I'll mix some quoted blocks from codeforces and my own notes so we can keep the original post close to our discussion.

The Z algorithm starts as:

> As we iterate over the letters in the string (index i from 1 to n - 1), we maintain an interval [L, R] which is the interval with maximum R such that 1 ≤ L ≤ i ≤ R and S[L...R] is a prefix-substring (if no such interval exists, just let L = R =  - 1). For i = 1, we can simply compute L and R by comparing S[0...] to S[1...]. Moreover, we also get Z[1](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107) during this.

This is simple and straightforward.

> Now suppose we have the correct interval [L, R] for i - 1 and all of the Z values up to i - 1. We will compute Z[i] and the new [L, R] by the following steps:
>
> - **If i > R, then there does not exist a prefix-substring of S that starts before i and ends at or after i.** If such a substring existed, [L, R] would have been the interval for that substring rather than its current value. Thus we "reset" and compute a new [L, R] by comparing S[0...] to S[i...] and get Z[i] at the same time (Z[i] = R - L + 1).

The bold part in the bullet point might be confusing, but if you read it twice, it's really just repeating the definition of *R*.

> - Otherwise, i ≤ R, so the current [L, R] extends at least to i. Let k = i - L. We know that Z[i] ≥ min(Z[k], R - i + 1) because **S[i...] matches S[k...] for at least R - i + 1 characters** (they are in the [L, R] interval which we know to be a prefix-substring). Now we have a few more cases to consider.

The bold part is not completely accurate, because R - i + 1 can be greater than Z[k], in which case Z[i] would be Z[k].

Let's focus on the key now: **Z[i] ≥ min(Z[k], R - i + 1)**. Why is this true? Because of the following:

- Based on the definition of interval [L, R] and i ≤ R, we already confirmed that S[0...R - L] == S[L...R], hence S[0...k] == S[L...i], and S[k...R - L] == S[i...R];
- Say Z[k] = x, based on the definition of Z, we know S[0...x] == S[k...k + x];
- Combined above equations, we know S[0...x] == S[L...L + x] == S[k...k + x] == S[i...i + x], when x < R - i + 1. The point is, S[k...k + x] == S[i...i + x], so Z[i] = Z[k] when Z[k] < R - i + 1.

These are the missing dots I mentioned in the beginning, and they explain both the second and the third bullet points, and partially the last bullet point. This wasn't straightforward when I read the codeforces post. To me this is the most important part of this algorithm.

For the last bullet point, if Z[k] ≥ R - i + 1, we would refresh [L, R], using i as the new L, and extending R to a bigger R'.

In the whole process, Z algorithm only uses each character once for comparison, so the time complexity is O(n).

As Ilya answered, the intuition in this algorithm is to carefully reuse every piece of information we gathered so far. I just explained it in another way. Hope it helps.